# diff command label format

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, diff

is it possible to get `header` or `label` on two diff file using `diff` or `sdiff` command or any other tool. following just example, we have a script which comparing 100s of file so it is good to know which one we are comparing..

currently:

```
# diff -y --suppress-common-lines /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
    how are you                                                   | How are you sir
    xxxxxxx
```

I want header or label something like following so it will looks good in report, otherwise i have to do `echo` etc.. to make it work

```
# diff -y --suppress-common-lines /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
    [file1]                                                            [file2]
  how are you                                                   | How are you sir
  xxxxxxx
                                                   <
```

Comment: `diff --help`, or use some other tool(s) that format the diff output the way you want.

Comment: @MarcB i read `man` but didn't find specific so i post here if people has different way or `utility` to make it, otherwise i have hack `echo`

Comment: Use unified diff output instead which includes header lines?

Comment: i need `side-by-side` that is the reason i need `header` :(

Comment: Try [vimdiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this or add it to your ~/.bashrc:

```
function mydiff() { echo -e " [${1##*/}]\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[${2##*/}]"; diff -y --suppress-common-lines $1 $2; }
```

and use this:

```
mydiff /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `vimdiff` or `vim -d` to check the file diff.

```
vimdiff /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
```